# SSH.NET ftpClient and Logging

Tags: c#-4.0, logging, sftp, ssh.net

I have a pretty basic routine for uploading files to a Secure FTP site using the SSH.NET library.  I am using the SftpClient object out of the library.  Everything is working correctly and I am not receiving any exceptions.  However, the company on the other end of the FTP is saying they are not receiving some files.  It appears random, and every single time I have manually verified that the files are on the FTP server, they have been.  So I suspect there is something going on on their side because after literally thousands of files to other clients there has never been a lost file...except with them.

So...I have been looking for logging options out of the SftpClient so that I can prove that the files have been actually uploaded.

Is there any way to get the FTP commands logged out of the library?  I am looking for the client and server response like the following example that was stolen from the web:

```
%   ftp nordsieck.cs.colorado.edu  
Connected to nordsieck.cs.colorado.edu.  
220 nordsieck FTP server (Version 5.53 Tue Aug 25 10:46:12 MDT 1992) ready.  
Name (nordsieck.cs.colorado.edu:yourlogin): yourlogin  
331 Password required for yourlogin.  
Password:  
230 User yourlogin logged in.  
ftp> cd HPSC/exercises  
250 CWD command successful.  
ftp> ls  
200 PORT command successful.  
550 No files found.  
ftp> put tmul.out  
200 PORT command successful.  
150 Opening ASCII mode data connection for tmul.out.  
226 Transfer complete.  
local: tmul.out remote: tmul.out  
1882 bytes sent in 0.0095 seconds (1.9e+02 Kbytes/s)  
ftp> ls  
200 PORT command successful.  
150 Opening ASCII mode data connection for file list.  
tmul.out  
226 Transfer complete.  
9 bytes received in 0.0021 seconds (4.3 Kbytes/s)  
ftp> mput *  
mput Makefile? y  
200 PORT command successful.  
150 Opening ASCII mode data connection for Makefile.  
226 Transfer complete.  
local: Makefile remote: Makefile  
1020 bytes sent in 0.0062 seconds (1.6e+02 Kbytes/s)  
mput tmul.out? n  
ftp> quit  
221 Goodbye.
```

Baring that, is there any other logging available?

Answer (score 0):

What you show is an FTP log. FTP is a text protocol (commands are sent in text) and so logging is pretty easy. SFTP is a completely different protocol with binary commands. Your best option is to add your own logging before and after calling each SFTP method.

Comment: Ah.  I just assumed the SFTP protocol was simply encrypting a typical FTP session.  I didn't realize it redefined the underlying protocol for the transfer of information.  That being said, I was able to dig through the source (it's open source as well) and get what logging I needed out of it.

Just out of curiosity, why do you believe SSH.NET is outdated?  It is still maintained and seems to work well.  I see you develop a competing product...does that have something to do with it? ;)

Comment: @MichaelStoner All those open-source names are so confusing ... there was an old library called SharpSSH and ssh.net tag mentions SharpSSH as a source.